# Windows 10 wake up from sleep is very slow

Tags: windows, windows-10, login, sleep, wake-up

I just recently did a clean install of Windows 10 Pro.
OS runs smoothly, boot time is not so bad (under 30s), but wake-up time is IMO terribly slow, at least compared to Windows 7, where I could work with system immediately.
In Windows 10 on the other hand, I have to wait 10 - 15 secs before OS becomes usable. I can't type my password right away, because login screen is unresponsive. With password on login disabled, I still have to wait like 15 secs before any programs/apps will respond.

Comment: Do you have any external USB drives attached or network shares? Have you tested your hard disk for SMART errors?

Comment: capture a xbootmgr trace of the sleep/resume (use the Win10 SDK/WPT: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk): http://pastebin.com/6vmuzcBp