# Windows 10 is unresponsive for a while after booting from sleep

Tags: windows, boot, performance, windows-10, sleep

I've found I have similar problem to the one posted yesterday:

[Windows 10 wake up from sleep is very slow](https://superuser.com/q/963592)

I've done a boot trace (like it was suggested by user magicandre1981).

http://1drv.ms/1Ep4XKk

I don't know how to interpret the results, so I'd like to ask any experienced user to analyze it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows is a bit slow after resume because Superfetch reads data again from HDD to later speed up the execution of applications.

[image]

Your `Hitachi Travelstar 5K500` HDD is very slow and your system is 6 years old (Acer Aspire 7540), so don't expect too much fun with a new Operating system on such an old system with only a AMD Athlon II Dual-Core CPU and such a slow HDD.

Comment: I do realise it, but I'm sure I didn't have this problem after my first installation of Windows 10 Pro. That's why I think it's not ok this time. Also, can I safely disable or at least delay Superfetch?

Comment: stopping the superfetch service will slow down your Windows a lot.